# Un/Marshalling from XMLConfiguration (commons-configuration) - How to get w3c-node

Tags: java, xml, configuration, marshalling, w3c

I want to use un/marshalling using JAXB with XMLConfiguration from commons-configuration.

I have an XMLConfiguration like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration>
    <display id="1">
        <name>name1</name>
    </display>
    <display id="2">
        <name>name2</class>
        <subdisplay>
            <header>subHeader</header>
        </subdisplay>
    </display>
</configuration>
```

Given that I have a xsd-Schema for that XML and generate the JAXB-Classes using xjc. How do I get a w3c-Node from `HierarchicalConfiguration` for example at a given level in the XML, e.g.:

```
XMLConfiguration conf = new XMLConfiguration("myFile.xml");

HierarchicalConfiguration displayConf = conf.configurationAt("display");
```

The Node that I can get from here seems to be a special commons-configuration Node. I get erros that it cannot be casted to the w3c Node needed to unmarshall from the configuration. Is there a way to get the w3c-Node from `XMLConfiguration` in a easy way? Or is there even a smoother way to perceive objects from `XMLConfiguration`?

Comment: commons config is really, really old.  You might be better off simply loading the XML and parsing it if you need a DOM.

Comment: The current system is already based on commons-config. So, is there a direct way to generate a DOM out-of-the-box or a simple workaround?

Comment: HierarchicalConfiguration knows nothing about XML. You will have to get the Document from XMLConfiguration#getDocument() and go from there.

Comment: Ah... I missed the point that the getDocument from XMLConfiguration is already a w3c-Document which implements Node. Thanks!